# Is it possible to eliminate $g(x)$ in the formula $\dfrac{\int g(x)a(x)}{\int g(x)b(x)}$

Tags: integration

I am hoping someone can show me how to do the following:

I have two integrals containing a function $g(x)$ that I would like
to eliminate.

The formula looks like this.

$\frac{\int g(x)a(x)}{\int g(x)b(x)}$

Is there any way to eliminate the $g(x)$ terms?

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Not in general.

Comment: Probably more like hardly ever.

Comment: People denote integrals in many different ways but the one used in this question is not one of them (you might want to add $dx$ at some well chosen places).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple counter example:
$$\begin{align}
g(x) &= x^k\\
a(x) &= x^m\\
b(x) &= x^n
\end{align}$$
Now
$$\frac{\int g(x)a(x)\,\mathrm dx}{\int g(x)b(x)\,\mathrm dx} = \frac{(k+m+1)^{-1}x^{k+m+1}+C_1}{(k+n+1)^{-1}x^{k+n+1}+C_2}$$
but
$$\frac{\int a(x)\,\mathrm dx}{\int b(x)\,\mathrm dx} = \frac{(m+1)^{-1}x^{m+1}+C_1}{(n+1)^{-1}x^{n+1}+C_2}$$
As you can see, not only does the presence of $g(x)$ make a difference, but the result also depends on the specifics of $g(x)$, like the value of $k$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I forgot to mention that I can change the value for $a(x)$ and $b(x)$, so long as they do not contain $g(x)$ terms if that makes sense? Sorry for not mentioning that!

Comment: @Paul: I have no idea what you want to say with that sentence. Could you perhaps give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Yes I see what you mean!
Thanks for the help.
Cheers